# Success does not fire after getJson

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a getjson method in jquery that fetches soe location data with this code

```
$.getJSON('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse', {
    lat: lat,
    lon: lng,
    format: 'json',
}, function (result) {
   var dn = result;
   var phn = localStorage.getItem("number");
    var new_dn = JSON.stringify(dn);
    $.ajax({ 
            url: 'http://cnn.com/nj.php' ,
            type : "POST",            
            data: {phone: phn, location: new_dn },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function()
            {
                alert('success'); 
            }            
      });
});
```

I want to do something on success but this code does not fire an alert

```
success: function()
                {
                    alert('success'); 
                }
```

Why is this so?.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the ajax call is actually successful?

Comment: Any errors in the [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: @CumminUp07 Yes, i get the data on the server side.

Comment: @PaulRoub I am building for android with cordova, trying with browser now but i am able to get posted data on the server side.

Comment: "Yes, i get the data on the server side". Unless you have access to cnn.com's servers, how are you seeing the `$.ajax()` call's server-side result? That `success` function won't be called when `getJSON` succeeds; it's called when the `ajax` call *within* `getJSON`'s callback succeeds.

Comment: @PaulRoub No error in console after trying it in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callback methods are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/